# Magento Website Crawl Issue - A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt

Tags: magento, meta-tags, robots.txt

I am working on this site and some how (I don't know why) Google stop crawling Home page URL (http://www.indusuno.com/), while checking this site in Google It shows (A description for this result is not available because of this site's robots.txt Learn more). I'm attaching the snapshot.

And also index.php is coming in url which any one search on website.
Earlier we have blocked index.php from robots.txt, but now allow this. (indusunocom/robots.txt)

Kindly help me to resolve this issue.

[image]

Comment: Check the search console at https://www.google.com/webmasters/ to see what errors googlebot is having indexing your site.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: @GrishaLevit - There is no issue or error showing in Google Console.

Comment: @Enigmativity - Ok, sorry for posting here, I was not aware about it.